# How to get String between innermost parentheses with Ansible?

Tags: regex, ansible

i have a following String that i get with Ansible debug module:

```
{
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python"
    },
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": [
        "check"
    ],
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "QMNAME(XXXXXX)                                STATUS(Running)",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "QMNAME(XXXXXX)                                STATUS(Running)"
    ]
}
```

The 'XXXXXXXX' varieties from server to server.

How can i get it?

i need to reuse it as part of systemd module:

```
- name: Check Status of the Services 
  systemd:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: started
  with_items:
    - "my-{{ server.stdout | regex_search('\\(([^()]+)\\)', '\\1') | trim }}-server"
  when: ('server' in group_names)
```

i have tried to trim it and cut it but since the size differs i get to less or to much.

```
- name: Check my_Server output
  debug:
    msg: "{{ server.stdout[7:-48] | trim }}"
  failed_when: "'STATUS(Running)' not in server.stdout"
  when: ('server' in group_names)
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor, many thanks. the output is msg: ["xxxx"]. Is it possible to remove the [], in order to get only "xxxxx"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to get the first string between parentheses excluding the parentheses themselves:

```
{{ server.stdout | regex_search('\\(([^()]+)\\)', '\\1') | trim }}
{{ server.stdout | regex_search('\\(([^()]+)\\)', '\\1') | list | first | trim }}
```

The `\(([^()]+)\)` pattern matches a `(` first, then one or more chars other than `(` and `)` (that are captured into Group 1, hence the `\1` later), and then a `)` char is matched, but not captured.

Using `trim` is still fine since the captured substring may still contain whitespace at the start and end.

To get multiple matches use

```
{{ server.stdout | regex_findall('\\(\\s*([^()]*?)\\s*\\)') }}
```

The `\(\s*([^()]*?)\s*\)` matches

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^()]*?)` - Group 1 (the return result of `regex_findall`): any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` as few as possible (so that the subsequent `\s*` could consume all whitespace chars before `)`)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: i just edited my question to show what i use the Variable for. currently i get my-[xxxx]-server

Comment: @AndrewRamnikov Try `{{ server.stdout | regex_search('\\(\\s*([^()]*?)\\s*\\)', '\\1') | list | first }}` or `{{ server.stdout | regex_search('\\(([^()]+)\\)', '\\1') | list | first | trim }}`